# Installation of Indeo codec in Windows 10 for Grove Music / Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-10, codec, avi, windows-media-player

I have been trying to open a video (.avi file) which I created a long time back. I had used Indeo codec for compressing the video. And now I can't open the avi-file in Windows 10.

Is there any way I can install Indeo codec for Grove Music or Windows Media Player in Windows 10?

Otherwise, is there any other option (may be a different player) to open the compressed avi file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) as it supports indeo (and you can use it to export in any other format that you need.)